# "Savings Wallets" application described in Ethereum whitepaper

Tags: white-paper

I have difficulty with understanding the concept of a wallet shared between Alice and Bob described in Ethereum whitepaper: [Further Applications](https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/#further-applications)  → Savings wallets:

> Suppose that Alice wants to keep her funds safe, but is worried that she will lose or someone will hack her private key. She puts ether into a contract with Bob, a bank, as follows:
>
> - Alice alone can withdraw a maximum of 1% of the funds per day.
> - Bob alone can withdraw a maximum of 1% of the funds per day, but Alice has the ability to make a transaction with her key shutting off this ability.
> - Alice and Bob together can withdraw anything.
>
> Normally, 1% per day is enough for Alice, and if Alice wants to withdraw more she can contact Bob for help. If Alice's key gets hacked, she runs to Bob to move the funds to a new contract. If she loses her key, Bob will get the funds out eventually. If Bob turns out to be malicious, then she can turn off his ability to withdraw.

My questions are:

1. How can Bob move the funds to a new contract when moving everything needs Bob and Alice together (Alice is hacked so how can she do something together with Bob?)
2. How can she turn off Bob's ability to withdraw if she was hacked?